# force signalr to re authorize user

Tags: asp.net, cookies, signalr

I'm using signalr and since I wanna use websockets the `[Authorize]` attribute only authorize the client when the connection opens and then everything is ok. I would like the `[Authorize]` process to be triggered somehow.

**Note: Must works using websockets**

For example (I use Owin.Security.Cookies (UseCookieAuthentication)):
I connect to my application with a valid token in my cookie, once I've done this I manually remove the cookie in my browser and everything still works OK until I reload the page. Another example is if the client already has an open and valid connection, but the token limit expires - it's still valid until a reload is done.

Now to my question - Is there anyway I can force signalr to re-authorize the token every x min?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the rest of this answer, I'm going to assume you're using SignalR hubs instead of PersistentConnections.

When you use SignalR's `[Authorize]` attribute or your own custom version of it, there are three methods to be aware of.

`AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation`

This is called, as you might expect, when a method on your hub is called. This could be any method, or only methods you apply an `[Authorize]` attribute to. You could put your code here.

`AuthorizeHubConnection`

This is probably what you want. Every time the client connects to the hub- which is a fairly frequent occurrence- this method is called. Do NOT confuse this with SignalR's Hub's idea of a connection. When a client is communicating with a SignalR hub, this method is called frequently- every method call or two on average.

This is where I would put the code you're talking about. You'll want to create a new attribute that inherits from `SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute`. In there, you'll want to override either `AuthorizeHubConnection` or `AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation`. Do note that if you don't override one of these methods, they will call `UserAuthorized` to make their decision.

In one of those two methods, you want them to return `true` if their cookie is valid (it exists, has a valid token, and hasn't expired), and `false` otherwise. This code will be called every time- or just about every time- a call is made to the hub, and deny access to the client if anything's wrong.

Hope this works!

Comment: Tried this, but it doesnt seems to call the `AuthorizeHubConnection` once the connection is opened

Comment: @MrProgram That's odd. It gets called all the time when I do it. Have you tried putting your code in `AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation`?

Comment: Are you sure you are using websockets and not longpolling then?

Comment: Try `console.log('Connection runs with: ' + $.connection.hub.transport.name);` after you started your Hub

Comment: I better be using websockets. That's what it says in Fiddler. Long Polling only gets used in a browser context, and we only have .NET clients.

Comment: Ok.. Well for me it seems like the AuthorizeHubConnection is called when the connection opens. Will try the other one as well

Comment: In my experience, AuthorizeHubConnection is called when a (low-level, underlying) connection opens, not necessarily when the client calls HubConnection.Start(). Your mileage may vary- I've never really used OWIN authentication.